# Repeated visits to the US on a multiple-entry tourist visa. Will I have any problems?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, multiple-entry, repeat-visits

I've been re entering US three times this year. First was last February 13 where I entered using a J1 visa but I had to comeback home after 4 days because of some misunderstanding with the sponsor. And then last March 10 I returned to US using a multi entry tourist (B) visa and left on March 31st. Then the third one was last May 22 and then I came back home recently which was 10th of August. And now I am planning to return next month using a multi entry tourist (B) visa again on the same city and state to visit someone.

Will there be any problem when I return to US with an immigration officer?

Comment: Well, maybe? Anybody can have problems with the immigration officer. The key things that might cause you extra problems are: For how long, and who are you visiting.

Comment: Why would there be any problem?

Comment: Im just worried because i've been re entering US every month for three time this year.. I'll just stay there for a month to visit a relative again,

Answer (score 6):

As long as on each trip, you state the proper reason, and have the proper visa, you should not have any issues.

They might get curious, and ask about it, but it is legal to travel in and out ten times a day if you feel like it, and if your visa permits it.